# Dialogflow: "Recursive" Intents flow (recap / edit / confirm and back)

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have an intent that is triggered thanks to an Event.
This Event sets the value of the intent parameters.
Anyway, there can be some mistake in the data (or missing, but this case is easy and not part of the question).
Now, let's make an example.
My intent has the following parameters:

- name (Dialogflow type person), value: "John Doe"
- birthday (Dialogflow type date), value: "1975-12-14"
- city (Dialogflow type geo-city), value: "Rome"

but my name is *Jack Doe*.

[image: confirmation flow]

The image describes the flow better than I can do, but I try to explain:

The bot, once he has all the required info, ask the user if he wants to confirm the values (there is a pre-defined intent to confirm).
If the answer is yes, I will save this info to my server thanks to a webhook, and we're done.
If the user wants to change something, we are in the case discussed in this thread.

> **User**: no
>
> **Bot**: what you want to change?
>
> **User**: name
>
> **Bot**: Ok, what's your name?
>
> **User**: Jack Doe

At this point I would like to go back to the intent that displays all the info and asks again for confirmation (of course the name will be "Jack Doe" in the second iteration).
The user can change the values over and over until he confirms that the values are correct.

I think that it could be crazy to create a flow of follow-up intents to catch all the possible branches (potentially infinite) and that maybe there is a way to accomplish this task in a smarter way.

Any ideas on how can I implement this flow? Or a variation that can obtain the same result?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but with "all the possible branches" you mean the different features that a user will be able to change right?

Comment: Hi Jordi. What I mean is that the user should be able to potentially answer "no" all the time he wants, change "name" all the time he wants, change "birthday" all the time he wants, change "city" all the time he wants..until he answers "yes"

Answer (score 3):

If you want the yes and no confirmation to be able to be triggered from any step you should make sure that they have no [input context](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/contexts-input-output#input_contexts). This way you will be able to trigger these intent even when you are in a step that has an active context. A simple example for how you could implement you flow would be like this:

[image]

When you say no in the welcome intent, you will start the change feature flow. Due to the *change which feature* and *input new feature value* intents being [follow-up intents](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/contexts-follow-up-intents), Dialogflow will try to match user input to those intents first before trying to match to *info correct* or *info incorrect* intents when their context is active, but if no match is found it will still trigger the info correct / incorrect intents.

If you only want them to be triggerable for a certain time, you should give all of these intents the same input context (besides the ones they need for the flow to work) and disable it once the user confirms that it is correct.

Comment: Thanks Jordi. Just a notice: I have "just" upvoted the answer at the moment, it's a very good and smart direction to follow. I will accept the answer in case it will fit and solve the problem, and I think it will be the case.